# Core Data migration with multiple models

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a iOS app that uses CoreData. The app which is live on the Apple Store, has V1 of my model and I have since upgraded to V2 using the standard technique of adding a new model via UI etc.

The app with V2 is not live yet and is being used by a few people for testing. There are some more changes to V2 which will obviously result in a V3 model.

My question is, if I go live with both V2 and V3 versions of the model, will the upgrade go through successfully.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can only have one Core Data model version marked as the 'current version' within an application. I'm assuming that what you want to know is whether its possible to upgrade from V1 to V3 and V2 to V3.  That answer depends on the specifics of the changes between your model versions as well as any explicit mapping models you may have created.  Posting any details like these would be helpful.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - having multiple simultaneous versions of a model in use in an app at once can work, but requires a lot of effort. Do you perhaps mean that you want to go live with V3 of the model and upgrade both V1 and V2 users to that?

Comment: @JonathanArbogast is right except of you can have one current version per model, not per application (You can have, for example two independent models, each with own versions). To determine, whether upgrade is possible read about https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html . Also i see no sense in migrating from V2 to V3, if lightweight migration is impossible. Perform migration between releases, not between test builds

Comment: I don't know what happened to the earlier answer, but it is possible to go from V2 -> V3 while having V1. I just tried it and it worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do multiple light weight migrations.

I have V1 of my model.. Then added a new entity for V2 and made that the current model.
After that I added a new model V3, and added a new attribute to the new entity created in V2.

Comment: As long as the older model versions are still in your project, your all good. If you had removed the V1 model, then you would be in trouble.